# What type of feature in JS/HTML/CSS is this site using?

Tags: css, html, web

I am interested in implementing what the banner that this site has, where the user upon scrolling the banner animates till the end and only which allows the viewer to move down the site. Here is the site http://www.nets.upenn.edu/

Comment: you could try this parallax library http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/

Comment: thats's using `canvas` HTML5 element with some `javascript` code.

Comment: That's a canvas animation (entirely Javascript), no CSS/HTML animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a plugin that i used in some project:

[ScrollMagic](http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/)

With this plugin it's easy to achieve a similar result like the canvas in your link.

Comment: You are welcome :) maybe you give me a +1 and sign the answer as the correct one :) @user3630406

Answer (score 0):

For the animated slider you can find out more by looking at these two JS files:

nets.upenn.edu/sites/all/themes/pennnets/js/slides.min.jquery.js 
nets.upenn.edu/sites/all/themes/pennnets/js/tween_scrollable.js

And for the second part of your question take a look at this link:

http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-parallax-plugin/

Good luck

Comment: I don't think those js files are accessible to public? . Thanks for the link its really useful.

Comment: when you copy and paste those links to your browser make sure you add www. at the beginning before you hit enter otherwise you will be redirected somewhere else